# Wrapping Great Circle arcs nicely in Mercator maps

Tags: c#, bing-maps, great-circle, mercator

I am using Bing Map Tiles and C#. This is a Silverlight application. In my application, I draw Great circle lines between locations on Mercator map. Everything works fine, till the circle tries to wrap around the map. For example, a great circle arc between, New York City and Tokyo is giving me a horizontal line (which I presume is line wrapping around the globe) along with the GC Arcs. I want to eliminate this horizontal line.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated??

Comment: Any sample code will be highly appreciated??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution would be to split the geometry into two geometries splitted over the meridian at +180° longitude. In this way you will be able to draw this without having the horizontal line.